# how to change ckeditor value by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ckeditor4.x

my textarea is:

```
<textarea class="content" name="content" id="content" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

and initializing it as:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        ///CKeditor
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
            height: 320,
        } );

    });
</script>
```

now i am getting data in an array and then changing the values of different elements according to it. the array that i am getting is:

```
[{"id":"5","subject_Id":"1","topic_id":"1","question_type_id":"4","exam_id":"1","difficulty_id":"1","year_id":"1","essay":"","right_marks":"2","negative_marks":"3","question":"question 2","options":"Ans CC~Ans BB~Ans AA~","correct_answer":"Ans BB~"}]

[{"id":"6","subject_Id":"1","topic_id":"1","question_type_id":"4","exam_id":"1","difficulty_id":"1","year_id":"1","essay":"","right_marks":"2","negative_marks":"3","question":"question 1","options":"<img alt=\"\" src=\"\/corePhp\/examinationsystem\/assets\/ckeditor\/kcfinder\/upload\/images\/profile-icon-9(1).png\" style=\"height:512px; width:512px\" \/>~Ans BB~Ans AA~","correct_answer":"Ans BB~"}]

[{"id":"18","subject_Id":"1","topic_id":"1","question_type_id":"1","exam_id":"1","difficulty_id":"1","year_id":"2","essay":"Essay 5","right_marks":"2","negative_marks":"3","question":"Brass gets discoloured in air because of the presence of which of the following gases in air?","options":"Oxygen~Hydrogen sulphide~Carbon dioxide~Nitrogen","correct_answer":"\"Hydrogen sulphide\""}]
```

then in my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function dbDataQuestion(quesId) {
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200)
            {
                var convert=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //console.log(convert[0].subject_Id);
                document.getElementById("selectSubject").value=convert[0].subject_Id;
                document.getElementById("selectTopic").value=convert[0].topic_id;
                document.getElementById("selectQuestionType").value=convert[0].question_type_id;
                document.getElementById("selectExam").value=convert[0].exam_id;
                document.getElementById("selectYear").value=convert[0].year_id;
                document.getElementById("selectDiffLvl").value=convert[0].difficulty_id;
                document.getElementById("txtRightMarks").value=convert[0].right_marks;
                document.getElementById("txtNegMarks").value=convert[0].negative_marks;
                console.log(convert[0].question_type_id);
                console.log(convert[0].question);

                CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)
                {
                    //CKEDITOR.instances.content.insertHtml(convert[0].question);
                    CKEDITOR.instances.content.focus();
                    CKEDITOR.instances.content.setData(convert[0].question);

                });

                if(convert[0].essay){
                    document.getElementById("txtEssayName").value=convert[0].essay;
                    document.getElementById("radioEssayYes").checked = true;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("txtEssayName").value=convert[0].essay;
                    document.getElementById("radioEssayNo").checked = true;
                }
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","process/questions/quesDetails.php?quesId="+quesId, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

as you can see i am consoling `console.log(convert[0].question);` in which i am getting correct data, but when i am writing `CKEDITOR.instances.content.setData(convert[0].question);` its not updating ck editor's value.

actually the function "dbDataQuestion(quesId)" is being called once at the time of page load at that time its working fine the CKEditor is showing `question 2` which you can see is in the first array, after that I have a button on which I am getting the next array and so on. on clicking this button array is getting displayed in the console as well as other element are changing its values but CKEditor is showing the same old value that is `question 1` and not `question 2` on consoling `console.log(convert[0].question);` I am getting "question 2" which is correct.

**Note:** `function dbDataQuestion(quesId)` is where from where i am getting above mentioned array and on `xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200` of the function i am changing the values of the elements which includes ck editor. its once called at the time of page load and then its being called on a button click:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="fetchQuestionDetails('next')">Next</button>
```

I am calling all my scripts at the bottom of the page.
thanks in advance.

**Update:**
I noticed that instanceReady event is not getting triggered by calling the function when the button is pressed. I altered my code to check

```
console.log(convert[0].question);
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)
{
    console.log(convert[0].question);
    console.log("sss");
    CKEDITOR.instances.content.focus();
    CKEDITOR.instances.content.setData(convert[0].question);
});
```

only `console.log(convert[0].question);` is getting triggered and none of the other `console` statements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the data you have posted above is that available inside the `instanceReady` event?

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam no consoling it inside instanceReady event i am not getting any response. can you help me correcting it... please..

Comment: does removing the `instaceReady` block and keeping the inside code as is doesnt work? i mean just comment out the line `CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event)`

Comment: were you able to solve your problem ? @rajesh

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam yes thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

try it the following way by moving the initialization inside the ajax response section.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dbDataQuestion(quesId);
});
```

Your function will look like this.

```
function dbDataQuestion(quesId) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            var convert = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //console.log(convert[0].subject_Id);
            document.getElementById("selectSubject").value = convert[0].subject_Id;
            document.getElementById("selectTopic").value = convert[0].topic_id;
            document.getElementById("selectQuestionType").value = convert[0].question_type_id;
            document.getElementById("selectExam").value = convert[0].exam_id;
            document.getElementById("selectYear").value = convert[0].year_id;
            document.getElementById("selectDiffLvl").value = convert[0].difficulty_id;
            document.getElementById("txtRightMarks").value = convert[0].right_marks;
            document.getElementById("txtNegMarks").value = convert[0].negative_marks;
            console.log(convert[0].question_type_id);
            console.log(convert[0].question);
            ///CKeditor
            CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
                height: 320,
            });

            CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (event) {
                //CKEDITOR.instances.content.insertHtml(convert[0].question);
                CKEDITOR.instances.content.focus();
                CKEDITOR.instances.content.setData(convert[0].question);

            });

            if (convert[0].essay) {
                document.getElementById("txtEssayName").value = convert[0].essay;
                document.getElementById("radioEssayYes").checked = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("txtEssayName").value = convert[0].essay;
                document.getElementById("radioEssayNo").checked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "process/questions/quesDetails.php?quesId=" + quesId, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thanks a lot @Muhammad Omer Aslam for responding, so quickly. i have not tried your answer but i ll try it and comment if it solved the problem or not but i found a way to make it work i removed instanceReady event and wrote

```
setTimeout(function(){
    CKEDITOR.instances.content.setData(convert[0].question);
}, 1000);
```

and its working fine.  but again thanks @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Comment: no problem @rajesh buddy what i suggested you is the same thing and you wont have to wait for it using the `setTimeout`. anyway glas it works for you